# Uploading a file to SharePoint, not using UNC or drive mapping

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, upload

I'm trying to upload files to SharePoint using VBA within Excel.

I found some urlmon code which has solved the file download.

I've seen code which focuses on Scripting.FileSystemObject using UNC, winhttp POST and SEND and the SP SDK but I've not been able to make the latter work due to site and software install limitations.

I need to directly upload, for e.g. to "http://example.com/foldername". I tried using Scripting.FileSystemObject with the URL.

I'm making a bold assumption that there is a VBA method other than UNC and winhttp POST/SEND for uploading files to SharePoint.

Code I've tried, copied from someone else's work on Stack Overflow.

```
Public Function UploadEICRs(ByVal file As String, uploadFolder As String)

Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

' Where you will enter Sharepoint location path
SharepointAddress = "https://example.com/test_folder/"
' Where you will enter the file path, ex: Excel file
LocalAddress = file
SPFolder = SharepointAddress & uploadFolder & "/"

Debug.Print SPFolder

Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
    FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SPFolder
End If

Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing

End Function


Sub uploadFiles()

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    HostFolder = GetFolder

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim LString As String
    Dim LArray() As String
    Dim CertFolder As String
    Dim ufile As String
    Dim pFolder As String
    
    LString = folder
    LArray = Split(LString, "\")
    
    For Each SubFolder In folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim file
    For Each file In folder.Files
        CertFolder = LArray(3)
        pFolder = LArray(0) & "\" & LArray(1) & "\" & LArray(2)
        Debug.Print CertFolder
        Debug.Print file
        Debug.Print pFolder
        ufile = file
        sendfile2 ufile, CertFolder, pFolder
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub sendfile2(ByVal file As String, sUrl As String, fPath As String)

On Error GoTo err_Copy

Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim sharepointUrl
Dim sharepointFileName
Dim tsIn
Dim sBody
Dim LlFileLength As Long
Dim Lvarbin() As Byte
Dim LobjXML As Object
Dim LstrFileName As String
Dim LvarBinData As Variant
Dim PstrFullfileName As String
Dim PstrTargetURL As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fldr
Dim f
Dim pw As String
Dim UserName As String
Dim RetVal
Dim I As Integer
Dim totFiles As Integer
Dim Start As Date, Finish As Date

Debug.Print file
Debug.Print sUrl

sharepointUrl = "https://example.com/folder/folder"

Set LobjXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

mypath = sharepointUrl & "/" & sUrl
Debug.Print mypath

LobjXML.Open "HEAD", mypath, False 'Check for Directory
LobjXML.Send
If LobjXML.StatusText = "NOT FOUND" Then
    'Create directory if not there
    LobjXML.Open "MKCOL", mypath, False
    LobjXML.Send
End If

Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(fPath & "\" & sUrl)
Debug.Print fldr

totFiles = fldr.Files.Count
For Each f In fldr.Files

  sharepointFileName = sharepointUrl & "/" & sUrl & "/" & f.Name
  Debug.Print sharepointFileName

    PstrFullfileName = fPath & "\" & sUrl & "\" & f.Name
    LlFileLength = FileLen(PstrFullfileName) - 1
    Debug.Print PstrFullfileName
    ' Read the file into a byte array.
    If LlFileLength <> 0 Then
      ReDim Lvarbin(LlFileLength)
      Open PstrFullfileName For Binary As #1
      Get #1, , Lvarbin
      Close #1
    End If
    ' Convert to variant to PUT.
    LvarBinData = Lvarbin
    PstrTargetURL = sharepointUrl & "/" & sUrl & "/" & f.Name

    ' Put the data to the server, false means synchronous.
    LobjXML.Open "PUT", PstrTargetURL, False
   ' Send the file in.
    LobjXML.Send LvarBinData

  'End If

  I = I + 1
  'RetVal = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, "File " & I & " of " & totFiles & " copied...")

Next f

  'RetVal = SysCmd(acSysCmdClearStatus)
  Set LobjXML = Nothing
  Set fso = Nothing


err_Copy:
If Err <> 0 Then
  MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
End If

End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
          sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the SharePoint API, in order to securely log in and add files to a document library.  If you can make HTTP calls from your VBA code, then you can use the [SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints), or you can download the [SharePoint 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585), and then reference the [Client-Side Object Model (CSOM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#basic-operations-with-the-sharepoint-net-client-object-model) .dlls from VBA.  Beware that most of Microsoft's examples are in C#, but are adaptable to VB.

Comment: Many thanks,I'll take a look at the REST API and see where it takes. Fingers crossed. If I'm able to create a workable solution I'll post it here.

Comment: Here's the code for uploading files to sharepoint. I can't take credit for it as nearly all of the code was grabbed from the good work of others on this site.